# DB connection problem in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a separate DB for one model in my application and in development
mode the connection is working properly, in production however it isn't.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  host: myhost
  username: root
  password:
  database: production_db

users_production:
  adapter: mysql
  host: myhost
  username: root
  password:
  database: other_db
```

The model that connects to the other database is called User but the
table it references in `other_db` is `smf_users` so my User.rb looks like
this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "users_#{RAILS_ENV}"
  set_table_name "smf_users"
end
```

In production I'm getting this error:

```
Mysql::Error: Table 'production_db. smf_users' doesn't exist:
```

Note how it is trying to connect to the wrong database and so isn't
finding the correct table.  As I say, this works in development mode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: At what point is the error thrown? Are you trying something like User.find() or is it through a relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found when using multiple databases that odd errors show up when doing associations.  Any chance you've got another model out there which `belongs_to :users` and you're expecting it to Just Work?  Otherwise, you have to look at caching -- it's easily possible that Rails is failing to cache the connection data for your extra database correctly.

Comment: Yes, that could be it.  Will the belongs_to :user fail in this case?

Comment: I think it would, and that would produce the error you're inquiring about.  I don't think you'll be able to use the associations DSL across multiple databases.  You can create your own :users method on the associated model, and within it say: User.all :conditions => [ 'associated_id = ?', id ].  Another option might be to mirror your User table into the other database using after_save callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
establish_connection configurations[RAILS_ENV]["users_#{RAILS_ENV}"]
User.connection
```

establish_connection needs a hash of the connection information. This should return if from database.yml.

You might want to check your log for a message like the following:

"users_production database is not configured"

That message would be thrown by ActiveRecord::Base if it can't find the congifuration by string in database.yml.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confident it's finding the config as I don't see that error.  I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with ActiveRecord caching the connection.

Comment: have you tried running configurations['users_production'] in a production console to confirm it's accesible?

Comment: This is very strange.  It works fine in the console if I type User.connection but when running through Passenger it hits up the wrong DB

Comment: So basically the settings work fine in a production console but don't work when running through the controllers (i.e. via a web connection).  Is it possible that the connection is being cached incorrectly when running through a web server?

Comment: You may need to reset the connection after making the configuration call. I've updated above.

Comment: The models all inherit from ActiveRecord::Base and share a mutual connection. The User model must clear itself from that shared connection. Which as mentioned as you mentioned, may have to be forced since caching values in a production environment hold on to that connection info. In essence, any call to find_by is going to use the existing connection unless explicitly told otherwise. Try calling connection directly within the model or prior to your finder.

Comment: Thanks but this still isn't working.  Again, in the console there's no problem but through a web server no good.

Tried putting User.connection in too...

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful: http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_multi_connections/